# How to select every column and last added columns that starts with XXXX from different tables?

Tags: mysql

First I'll start with my three tables:

### *Pictogram*

1. IDPictogram (INT)
2. Pictogram (BLOB)

### *Residents*

1. IDResident (INT)
2. Name (VARCHAR)
3. Photo (BLOB)

### *Schemes*

1. IDScheme (INT)
2. Resident (INT) INDEX -> IDResident
3. Activity1 (INT) INDEX -> IDPictogram
4. Activity2 (INT) INDEX -> IDPictogram
5. Activity3 (INT) INDEX -> IDPictogram
6. Activity4 (INT) INDEX -> IDPictogram
7. Activity5 (INT) INDEX -> IDPictogram
8. Activity6 (INT) INDEX -> IDPictogram
9. Activity7 (INT) INDEX -> IDPictogram

And the default value of Activity is NULL because not every resident will always have 7 activities per day. And I have a select like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM ActiviteitenSchemaO A,
    Bewoners B,
    Pictogrammen P
WHERE 
    A.Bewoner = B.IDBewoner
    AND A.Activity1 = P.IDPictogram
    OR A.Activity1 = NULL
    AND A.Activity2 = P.IDPictogram
    OR A.Activity2 = NULL
    AND A.Activity3 = P.IDPictogram
    OR A.Activity3 = NULL
    AND A.Activity4 = P.IDPictogram
    OR A.Activity4 = NULL
    AND A.Activity5 = P.IDPictogram
    OR A.Activity5 = NULL
    AND A.Activity6 = P.IDPictogram
    OR A.Activity6 = NULL
    AND A.Activity7 = P.IDPictogram
    OR A.Activity7 = NULL
```

What I want is to select every activity columns, that is linked to the pictogram, because each pictogram represents an activity and so.

**Problem 1:**
In the table schemes, all the activities are set to be NULL as default and will be filled in by an admin with activities, and my select doesn't work.

**Problem 2:**
The admin might add another activity place for a resident so he'll have 8 activities instead of 7. How do I make sure that all the columns starting with the word "Activity" will also be automatically selected?

Comment: I'm not very keen of your table structure... Did you consider creating a new table for your many-to-many relationship Activity? Here you might get some idea: http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/many-to-many-relationships/

Comment: AFAIK you can't solve Problem 2 this way. Doing what @EdwinKrause suggests might help. I'd say making dynamic table structure is rarely a good practice.

Comment: @EdwinKrause So should i make a new table "Activities" and then what? how will I link it? in my same old way? like between IDPictogram and the activities?

Comment: @Fox and how about problem 1? will it get solved if I make another table many-to-many for activities?

Comment: It will completely change the structure of your query, so it will probably fix your problem with the ugly WHERE clause, which, I believe, suffers from precedence issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the table structure.

Schemes should become:

```
Schemes
----------------
IDScheme (INT)
Resident (INT) INDEX -> IDResident
Activity (INT) INDEX -> ActivityID
```

and add Activity

```
Activity
----------------
ActivityID
IDPictogram
```

then your select can be simpler

```
SELECT *
FROM Bewoners B,
    Pictogrammen P,
    Activity a,
    Schemes s
WHERE 
    A.Bewoner = B.IDBewoner
    a.activityID = s.activityID
    p.IDPictogram  = a.IDPictogram
```

Comment: Why the activity column in Schemes? I'd go for Activity table with IDScheme and IDPictogram column ... Oh, and actually this might lose the position information, if it is important. That could be solved by adding Position column to Activity table.

Comment: schemes seems to be the link between the activity and the resident.

Comment: @Randy sorry for answering now but got busy. anyway thank you Randy for your answer, but doesn't mean this structure will make for each record (for each resident) only one activity? I mean I don't really get it now. I should have for each resident 7 activities per day. Am I will be having 7 records for each resident or what? Can you explain a little bit? Thank you

Comment: There are a lot of activities actually, not only 7. But per resident, there will be 7 activities per day and they are not always the same. If I follow your structure I believe the activity will be the same everyday. Like in the table Activity: 
activity1 = pictogram24, 
activity2 = pictogram31,
...
activity7 = pictogram11
So I won't be able to specify the activity, they will be static. Do you get what I want? Or did I get it wrong?
So I need a little bit explanation here. Thank you